# NEO4J Match slow vs. MySQL

Tags: neo4j

I am new to NEO4J but have been working with MySQL for many years. Now I have created a database with 700 000 user, 800 000 cookbooks and 1,6M saved recipes i NEO4J.

The structure of the nodes are like this (:User)-[:CREATED]-(:Cookbook)-[:SAVED]-(:Recipe). All the users and recipes are unique, but one user can have multipel cookbooks and every cookbook can have multipel recipes.

I use a EC2 m3.x2large, so it is quite fast. But the performance is very bad. This query:

MATCH (r:Recipe{recipe_id:2987431}) return r;

Take between 300-500 ms and mysql can execute it in around 2 ms.

Is this usual or have I configured the server all wrong?

(I have an index on :Recipe(recipe_id) )

Comment: is your index a unique constraint? like in `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE`?

Comment: No it's not normal because here you only use the index. For example on my computer this kind of query with the same volumetry take 10ms. 
To test the query, do you use the browser or neo4j-shell ?

Comment: Thanks! Now I tried it in neo4j-shell it is only 6 ms, but still slow in web interface... Do you have any idea why it is like that?

Answer (score 1):

Has your index come online yet?  If you run `:schema` in the console it should list all of the constraints / indexes and if they've yet been fully scanned and are online and available for use.

Comment: Yes they are all online.

Comment: That is really strange...  Have you done the query since you checked?  It could be that it came online since your last query (I might be straw grasping, but it's good to check).  It definitely shouldn't take that long with an index

Comment: Try also running `PROFILE MATCH (r:Recipe{recipe_id:2987431}) RETURN r` to see what it's trying to do (the web console should give you nice output here)